# Add the Shadow effect to fonts using CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, shadow

Hey everyone,
Again I need your help :D

Is it possible to add the shadow effect to the text in HTML using only CSS ?? I'm working on a project that has a lot of buttons and I need to find a way to add the shadow effect to the text in them without using images and to be compatible with the most used browsers. I tried using the "text-shadow" property in the CSS but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, here is the syntax:

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
```

Generally:

```
text-shadow: x y blur color;
```

and a link to the page I found it: http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/.

Comment: **You don't need the prefixes**. `text-shadow` is CSS2.1, not 3, which is why no vendor prefixes are needed. Even the page you link to says so.

Comment: Opps, my mistake, I confused the prefixes with box-shadow. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And you can find several answer to your question via Google, but this is one of the bests: http://www.kremalicious.com/2008/04/make-cool-and-clever-text-effects-with-css-text-shadow/

Answer (score 0):

As IE is still the most used browser, I´m afraid the answer is no.

However, if you are willing to let go of your requirement of *only css*, you can use for example [this jQuery plugin](http://www.iofo.it/jquery/fonteffect/).

Answer (score 0):

While this question has been answered already, I thought it worth adding that it's possible to add support for IE8, using the following `filter`s:

```
filter: glow(color=#ffff00,strength=3);
filter: dropshadow(color=#ffff00,offX=5,offY=5);
```

Unfortunately this only seems to work **if** the element has `display: block;` **and** a defined `height` (or) `width`; **or** the element has `position: absolute;` which is a little less than wonderful.

Citing my source for this: [Text-shadow, at: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/textshadow.html](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/textshadow.html), although I'm unable to verify the accuracy, since I don't routinely use IE (any version) or Windows, given the chance.